# Best consistent module imports with multiple submodules runnable as stand alone scripts

Tags: python, python-import

I have a project like this:

main --> run.py

main --> setup.py

main --> src --> main.py

main --> tests --> tests.py

Both *src* and *tests* folders have submodules that I would like to be able to run. However, I would like to import them in *main.py* and *tests.py* as respectively *src.submodule1.script1* or *tests.submodule2.script2* such that if I run *run.py* or *setup.py*, no import error appears.

**Why**:

1.It is quite boring to always make a function in *run.py* to test a function in a submodule and keep the scope three consistent.

2. I don't want to use the *__main__* variable to distinguish what scope it is.
3. I use sphinx as documentation tool (located in main --> docs), and it's clearer to see src.main or src.submodule1.script1 in function declaration.

**So far**:

In each file I create, I use the following method to import modules:

```
# main --> src --> main.py
import os
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
import src.submodule1.script1
```

**My question is: do you know a better way of handling such a structure ?**